# Cannot open .doc files

Tags: libreoffice

As far as I understand, LibreOffice Writer should be able to open .doc files. Mine is not working. It says "File type OLE2 compound document storage (application/x-ole-storage) is not supported". How do I fix this??  Please help!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

LibreOffice does usually, with the right filters, open .doc files. But the file you are trying to open is something more than a wordprocessor document. See this link:

[Microsoft's explanation of compound Documents](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms693383%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

As the error message says, it is an application/x-ole storage file. Here is more information

[wikipedia article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Compound_document)

In the LibreOffice File Open dialog click on File Type and from the list select a type that is appropriate for the document that your are trying to open.

Regards.

Comment: So essentially, I will be never be able to open this file type using LibreOffice?

Comment: @Sandy I think what graham is trying to say is to first open up LibreOffice Writer (without a document), and then go to the File-->Open menu, select the document, and then specify that it is a Microsoft Word ".doc" file.

Comment: I tried it. I think what the problem is, is whatever formatting that was previously used (its an ethics application) to make the tables expandable, LibreOffice Writer does not support. It will open the file if I save it as a .docx, but the format is all messed up and it does not allow me to correctly enter information into the tables.

Answer (score 2):

Try right-clicking on a .doc file, go the `open with` tab and select `Libreoffice Writer`

[image]